# Find numbers located most closely to the location of a specific sign in string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to get wage data out of a long vector of (very long) strings. My hunch is to filter for the location of the Dollar sign (either `$`, `usd` or `dollar`) and then to extract the number which is closest (in location) to the location of the Dollar sign.

I can't extract the numbers from the string directly because the strings follow no particular system (e.g. not all numbers indicate wage data and relative location of Dollar sign and numbers vary).

Some sample data and the Dollar names:

```
dollarnames <- tolower(c("USD", "Dollar", "[$]"))

salarylist <- c("Earn USD 5 per hour with us It is a lot of fun and you only have to work for 6 hours per day. We pay more USD than our competitors.",
                "You can become rich, too. Earn 50.000 Dollar per month and enjoy 60.000 pieces of cake per day. Enjoy Dollar! ",
                "Do you want to earn a lot of $? Then come and work with us. Earn $ 120.000 per year")
```

I want this as output:

```
# earnings
# 1        5
# 2    50000
# 3   120000
```

I guess that `str_locate` helps in one way or the other:

```
map(dollarnames, str_locate, string = tolower(salarylist))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the example you could just extract numbers preceded by `USD` or `$` or followed by the word `Dollar`, ie a simple look-ahead/look-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
(?i)(?<=(?:usd|dollar|[$])\s{0,100})\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*(?:usd|dollar|[$]))
```

with `stringr::str_extract` or `str_extract_all`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ib2J98/1/).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `(?<=(?:usd|dollar|[$])\s{0,100})` - a constrained-width lookbebind matching `usd`, `dollar` or `$`, then 0 to 100 (adjust it if there can be more than 100 spaces between the currency symbol and the number) whitespaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - "price" pattern: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - a "price" pattern
- `(?=\s*(?:usd|dollar|[$]))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces, and then `usd`, `dollar` or `$` char.

[R demo](https://tio.run/##dVLLbtQwFN3nKw5mFjaEKEVqF1WHbKYL1oAQIgi5iYeYJnZke5iJCN8@XDsRLRVk5Vydl8@1O59b2/fSGTkoj5tXCLa3R@V4w9mHdzuWg@0SIJ4@b74wIbLMSxpMvfYhMgh5SwIgOC4xKofOHhyOOnQ4eLwN0B4SvQ2we@wPBtK0mOwB1vQTOvlDkSuO1t1jbx2uEt8npVZOBT4qjHLCYJ1KJqGTBtGiscOogg7W@YLlGZ587BN5NIS9U4RUcLrpcrKyBVLgy7IoyxLL/ZLdYA2FjvGU@W4nXC2IUauG2qH0jbxXD8FuE2jhP8O/EuxsuuhRmhDvqKLtnyo2Fd53yiCFi6apgrW3NeMGF6/XEOQ6kQCjBfT6ztEGuA9Om29OZG1cxCh9UCVnvLpmefrhj5abkw/9jF5t2cwErVOQ1EilqEhmdd2@JGZdF/EkKpa509@qWvDqZksPoc0j3P8s84uy/CVokmRoOj8682pLoBcrPpq5U/Yci841LXJempvrjSAcaSfmmzVHkVKI@T/zxHiiklEfXwcZmo4/PNEc7iTO598):

```
dollarnames <- tolower(c("USD", "Dollar", "[$]"))

salarylist <- c("Earn USD 5 per hour with us It is a lot of fun and you only have to work for 6 hours per day. We pay more USD than our competitors.",
                "You can become rich, too. Earn 50.000 Dollar per month and enjoy 60.000 pieces of cake per day. Enjoy Dollar! ",
                "Do you want to earn a lot of $? Then come and work with us. Earn $ 120.000 per year")

library(stringr)
d <- paste0("(?:",paste(dollarnames, collapse="|"), ")")
price <- "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"
rx <- paste0("(?i)(?<=", d, "\\s{0,100})", price, "|", price, "(?=\\s*", d, ")")
str_match(salarylist, rx)
```

Output:

```
[1,] "5"      
[2,] "50.000" 
[3,] "120.000"
```

Comment: Note that the https://regex101.com/r/Ib2J98/1/ demo is based on JavaScript flavor, note that right now, you may see correct results in Chrome and Edge, FireFox will start supporting lookbehinds on June 30, see [compatibility matrix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind). There is no online regex tester I know where we could test ICU regexps unfortunately. The closest is probably [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), but it is more Java oriented and not that descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

if we focus on the word "per" we can extract with this code:

```
stringr::str_extract(salarylist , "\\d+.*?per \\w+")

[1] "5 per hour" "50.000 Dollar per month" "120.000 per year"
```

Comment: does the job but I cannot use the word "per" because it is not always included in the string. Sorry, should have specified that

Comment: @BeSeLuFri Sounds like you have too much variability in your inputs. Undoubtedly there will need human powered manual sorting of your data as there is no "one size fits all" solution.